# setState method works sometimes and sometimes doesn't in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

I'm trying to navigate between the loading screen and the main app screen using the inline if in the body parameter of the Scaffold object of the main Screen , using the code :

```
body : data == null?
Center(
  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
)
:(
data1 == null?
Center(
  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
)
:Center(child: Text('Data imported successfully'),)
),
```

**Note : the data1 is delayed with 10 sec from the data.**

so I needed a setState so when the two conditions  have false value the **Data imported successfully** text appears in the middle of the screen , I'm importing the data and the data1 in the initState of the main screen with the code :

```
void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    createDatabase()
        .then((value){
          getDataFromDatabase().then((value){setState(() {});});
        });
    createDatabase1()
        .then((value){
          getDataFromDatabase1().then((value){setState(() {});});
    });
  }
```

sometimes the code work properly and sometimes doesn't

I wonder why this is happening and how can I solve it ?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code that reduce your line of code as well as rebuild of flutter page

```
void initState() {
        // TODO: implement initState
        super.initState();
        Future.delayed(Duration.zero,(){
          _createDatabaseFunc();
        });
      }
    
      Future<void> _createDatabaseFunc() async {
        var firstDB = await createDatabase();
        var data = await getDataFromDatabase();
        var firstDB1 = await createDatabase1();
        var data1 = await getDataFromDatabase1();
        setState(() {}); // only single time refresh 
      }
```

Comment: I tried your code but unfortunately it didn't work in my case , however I tried to use the delayed function inside the then function of the getdatabase1 ,giving the duration Duration.zero and the callback was a setState and hopefully that worked , still having a little question what is the benefit of using the Duration.zero and what are the diffrences between using the setState  as a callback function in the delayed method and using it inside the then function for the same method

Comment: Duration.zero is waiting until code is executed successfully or failure(i.e taking some infinite time in some case or processing time) but if you specify duration (i.e 3 ms,4 ms) and code is not executed then it will missing some data....SetState is only used while after all the code of function is executed because many setState all time refresh page so whole data which will create load on app memory

Answer (score 2):

change you `initState` to this:

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  Future.wait([
    createDatabase().then((value) => getDataFromDatabase()),
    createDatabase1().then((value) => getDataFromDatabase1().timeout(Duration(seconds: 10))),
  ]).then((List<dynamic> results) {
    setState(() {
      data = results[0];
      data1 = results[1];
    });
  }).catchError((error) {
    // Handle any errors
  });
}
```

I hope I could solve your problem.

Comment: I tried your code but unfortunately it didn't work in my case , however I tried to use the delayed function inside the then function of the getdatabase1 ,giving the duration Duration.zero and the callback was a setState and hopefully that worked , still having a little question what is the benefit of using the Duration.zero and what are the diffrences between using the setState as a callback function in the delayed method and using it inside the then function for the same method